# I want the user to return to while loop after game finishes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Take input from user 1

```
player_1 = input("Enter your choice player_1 from rock,paper or scissor: ")
```

Take input from player 2

```
player_2 = input("Enter your choice player_2 from rock,paper or scissor: ")
```

Rules of rock paper scissor 1- paper covers rock 2- rock beats scissors 3- scissors cut paper

```
answer = []
while True:
    if player_1 == player_2:
        print("The game is tied sorry!!")
    elif player_1 == "paper" and player_2 == "scissor":
        print("scissor beats paper player_2 won")
    elif player_1 == "scissor" and player_2 == "paper":
        print("scissor beats paper player_1 won")
    elif player_1 == "rock" and player_2 == "paper":
        print("paper covers rock player_2 won")
    elif player_1 == "paper" and player_2 == "rock":
        print("paper covers rock player_1 won")
    elif player_1 == "scissor" and player_2 == "rock":
        print("rock breaks scissor player_2 won")
    elif player_1 == "rock" and player_2 == "scissor":
        print("rock breaks scissor player_1 won")

    answer = input("Do you want to play the game again? y or n : ")
    if answer == "y":
        continue 
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Then don't `break` out of the loop.

Comment: Is it Christmas already? So much whitespace

Comment: So what is your `exact`question ? your code is split into 3 parts, and if i'm *guessing* right, I have an idea of why you don't achieve intended behavior. However, the said behavior mustly express clearly using human words. If you do so, I might say that you won't need us to fix your isssue.

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = []
black5 = True
while black5:

    player_1 = input("Enter your choice player_1 from rock,paper or scissor: ")
    player_2 = input("Enter your choice player_2 from rock,paper or scissor: ")

    if player_1 == player_2:
        print("The game is tied sorry!!")
    elif player_1 == "paper" and player_2 == "scissor":
        print("scissor beats paper player_2 won")
    elif player_1 == "scissor" and player_2 == "paper":
        print("scissor beats paper player_1 won")
    elif player_1 == "rock" and player_2 == "paper":
        print("paper covers rock player_2 won")
    elif player_1 == "paper" and player_2 == "rock":
        print("paper covers rock player_1 won")
    elif player_1 == "scissor" and player_2 == "rock":
        print("rock breaks scissor player_2 won")
    elif player_1 == "rock" and player_2 == "scissor":
        print("rock breaks scissor player_1 won")

    answer = input("Do you want to play the game again? y or n : ")
    if answer != "y":black = False
```

Will continue if y is choosen adn exit if n is choosen.